# Using data types from a objective-c++ framework in a swift datamodel

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, opencv, bridging-header

I want to use the `openCV2 framework` in my `iOS` app, however, I am more comfortable with `swift`.  I can read and understand `obj-c` well enough to understand the framework and write the `methods` I need from it in a `bridging header`, but I'm not comfortable writing the whole app in `obj-C`.  Unfortunately, there are some `data types`, (`cv::Mat`, `cv::MserManager`, etc) that I will need to use in my datamodel, or possibly elsewhere.  Is there a way to include `datatypes` in my `bridging header` so that I can work with them in `swift`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use C++ types in code called from Swift.  However, you can use them in Objective-C++ files, the ones that have the `.mm` extension.  You can mix Objective-C and C++ code in Objective-C++, and can expose Objective-C methods that don't reference C++ in their declarations to Swift via the bridging wrapper.  These functions can still use C++ in their implementations, which are not visible in Swift via the bridging header.

You also need to be careful about the language linkage (remember `extern "C"`?).

Here are some answers that provide examples:

1) [Video processing with OpenCV in IOS Swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413951/video-processing-with-opencv-in-ios-swift-project/37427098#37427098)

2) [Include C++ header file in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37804467/include-c-header-file-in-swift/37872521#37872521)

3) [How to access Swift-objects from a c++ class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189814/how-to-access-swift-objects-from-a-c-class/39421973#39421973)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot bridge C++ and Objective-C++ directly into Swift. On the bright side, you can still work with the openCV2 framework in your app, but you'll need to write C or Objective-C wrappers for your types as described in a related question here: [Can I mix Swift with C++? Like the Objective - C .mm files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042774/can-i-mix-swift-with-c-like-the-objective-c-mm-files)